# The text in a JTextArea is not updating

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I find that my code does not update the text in a JTextArea.  I create a frame and add a couple of panels.  One of the panels contains my JTextArea.  Initially I set is as " ".  Then later on a button click, amongst other code, I update the JTextArea.  However, the update does not show up on the screen.

Here are snippets of my code:

```
static JFrame window = new JFrame("Valedictorian Voting System");
static JTextArea voteNotification = new JTextArea(" ");

static JPanel options = new JPanel();
static JPanel options1 = new JPanel();
static JPanel options2 = new JPanel();
```

Then in my main():

```
ImageIcon header;
ImageIcon side;
ImageIcon side2;
Image image = new ImageIcon("src\\Header_MICHS.jpg").getImage();    
header = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(290, 55, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
Image image2 = new ImageIcon("src\\lightningbolt2.png").getImage() ;    
side = new ImageIcon(image2.getScaledInstance(50, 235, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
Image image3 = new ImageIcon("src\\lightningbolt.png").getImage() ;  
side2 = new ImageIcon(image3.getScaledInstance(50, 235, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
JLabel sideLabel2 = new JLabel(side2);
JLabel sideLabel = new JLabel(side);
JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel(header);

//bottom bar add - the text field and Jbutton
JPanel studentInfo = new JPanel();
studentInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
studentInfo.add(studentNumber);
studentInfo.add(studentNumButton);



//add the val radio buttons to a panel
JPanel options1 = new JPanel();
options1.setLayout(new GridLayout(val2.length,0));
for(int i=0; i<val2.length;i++){
  options1.add(val2[i]);
}

//add the message box to a panel

options2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
options2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
options2.add(voteNotification);


//add the panels to a panel

options.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
options.add(options1);
options.add(options2);

//put the functional things into one panel
JPanel setup = new JPanel();
setup.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setup.add(options, BorderLayout.CENTER);
setup.add(studentInfo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//put the pictures around the functional things
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
content.add(setup, BorderLayout.CENTER);
content.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
content.add(sideLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
content.add(sideLabel2, BorderLayout.WEST);


window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
window.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
window.setContentPane(content);
window.setSize(300,310);
window.setLocation(550,250);
window.setVisible(true);  
window.setResizable(false);
```

This all works.  But when I click on the "Voted" button...everything works except the JTextArea is not updated.

```
public static boolean checkSelected(){
   stillVotable = checkNum();
   boolean selected = false;
   for(int i = 0; i<numVals; i++){
     if(val2[i].isSelected() && stillVotable==true){
        votes[i] +=1;

        voteNotification.setText("Student No.: " + studentNumber.getText() + " voted for: " + val.get(i));
        options2.repaint();



        System.out.println("Voted for " + val.get(i) + ":" + votes[i]);
        selected = true;
        checkWinner();//checks to see if someone won
        return true;
      }
    }
    if(selected==false && stillVotable==true)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not selected a Valedictorian!");
    else
      selected=false;
    return false;
  }
```

I am worried that it has to do with threading as I have not understood the descriptions in some of the other posts...

Here is all of the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class StandaloneGUIVotingSystem/* extends JApplet*/{

  static JFrame window = new JFrame("Valedictorian Voting System");
  static HintTextField studentNumber = new HintTextField("Enter student #!");
  static JTextArea voteNotification = new JTextArea("This is where your confirmation message will show up.");
  static ButtonGroup studentGroup;
  static JRadioButton[] val2;
  static int[] votes;

  static JPanel options = new JPanel();
  static JPanel options1 = new JPanel();
  static JPanel options2 = new JPanel();

  static CreateFile creator = new CreateFile();
  static FileHandling fileH = new FileHandling();

  static int studentsVoting = 0;
  static int numVals = 0;
  static int studentsVoted = 0;
  static boolean stillVotable = false;
  static String filePath = "src//";

  static DynamicArrayOfString studentNum = new DynamicArrayOfString();
  static DynamicArrayOfString val = new DynamicArrayOfString();

  //Window window; applet stuff

  //checks the student number entered to confirm a valid vote from a student that has not voted


  public static boolean checkNum(){ 
    for(int i = 0; i<studentNum.size(); i++){
      if(studentNumber.getText().equals(studentNum.get(i))){
        return true;
      }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is not a valid student number. Please enter a different one!");
    return false;
  }

  //checks to see if the user has selected a radio button


  public static boolean checkSelected(){
    stillVotable = checkNum();
    boolean selected = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<numVals; i++){
      if(val2[i].isSelected() && stillVotable==true){
        votes[i] +=1;

        voteNotification.setText("Student No.: " + studentNumber.getText() + " voted for: " + val.get(i));
        options2.repaint();



        System.out.println("Voted for " + val.get(i) + ":" + votes[i]);
        selected = true;
        checkWinner();//checks to see if someone won
        return true;
      }
    }
    if(selected==false && stillVotable==true)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not selected a Valedictorian!");
    else
      selected=false;
    return false;
  }

  //resets the screen for the next user


  public static void clear(){
    studentNumber.setText("");
    studentGroup.clearSelection();
    studentNumber.showHint();
    voteNotification.setText("");
  }

  public static void write(){
    //write winner file
    CreateFile.openFile("Winner.txt");
    CreateFile.addToFile("The Results of the Voting Contest are:");
    for(int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++){
      CreateFile.addToFile(val.get(i) + " has " + votes[i] + " votes.");
    }
    CreateFile.closeFile();

    //write voter file
    CreateFile.openFile("Voters.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < studentNum.size(); i++){
      CreateFile.addToFile(studentNum.get(i));
    }
    CreateFile.closeFile();
  }

  //removes the person who voted from the text file so they can only vote once
  public static void removeVoted(){
    for(int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++){
      if(studentNumber.getText().equals(studentNum.get(i))){
        studentNum.remove(i);
        studentsVoted++;
      }
    }
  }

  //checks if there is a winner and finishes program if there is
  public static void checkWinner(){

  if (studentsVoted == studentsVoting){
      int j=0;
      int largest = votes[0];  
      for(int i = 1; i < votes.length; i++){  
        if(votes[i] > largest){  
          largest = votes[i];  
          j = i;
        }  
      }
      CreateFile.openFile("Winner.txt");
      CreateFile.addToFile("The Results of the Voting Contest are:");
      for(int i = 0; i<val.size();i++){
        CreateFile.addToFile(val.get(i) + " has " + votes[i] + " votes.");
      }
      CreateFile.addToFile("\n");
      CreateFile.addToFile("Therefore, the winner is...");
      CreateFile.addToFile("");
      CreateFile.addToFile("");
      CreateFile.addToFile("");
      CreateFile.addToFile(val.get(j) + " wins!");
      CreateFile.closeFile();
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  //retrieves the initial information
  public static void retrieve(){
    //takes the student numbers and adds them to the dynamic array called studentNum
  fileH.openFile("Voters.txt");
    fileH.readFile();
    studentsVoting = fileH.length();
    for(int i = 0; i<studentsVoting;i++){
      studentNum.put(i, fileH.get(i));
    }
    fileH.closeFile();

    //gets the valedictorian names and puts them in the array val
    fileH.openFile("Valedictorians.txt");
    fileH.readFile();
    numVals = fileH.length();

    //for testing
    System.out.println(numVals);


    for(int i = 0; i < numVals;i++){
      val.put(i, fileH.get(i));

      //for testing
      System.out.println(val.get(i));
    }   
      val2 = new JRadioButton[numVals];
      votes = new int[numVals];

    fileH.closeFile();

    //takes the number of votes and places them in the votes array
    fileH.openFile("Winner.txt");
    fileH.readFile();
    int h = 0;
    for(int i = 9; i<fileH.length(); i += 4){

        System.out.println(fileH.get(i));

        votes[h]= Integer.parseInt(fileH.get(i));

      //for testing
      System.out.println("Votes for:" + val.get(h) + " are: "+ votes[h]);


      h++;
    }
    fileH.closeFile();

  }


  //if the user hits the vote button this method will run the steps needed to accomplish that goal
  public static void voted(){
    checkSelected();//checks student number, and adds a vote to the person selected
    removeVoted(); // removes the person who voted so that each person can only vote once



    clear();//clears the studentNumber and val selected
    write();// writes the updated info to the files Voters and Winner
    checkWinner(); //checks to see if the vote was the last

  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    retrieve();


    studentGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    //initalizes the names of each val on to radio buttons
  //adds each radio button to the button group and sets the background to white for a clear gui look
    for(int i = 0; i<numVals;i++){
      val2[i] = new JRadioButton(val.get(i));
      studentGroup.add(val2[i]);
      val2[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    voteNotification.setEditable(false);


    //vote button - allows the user to let the program know that they are done entering their student number and selecting a person for their vote
    JButton studentNumButton = new JButton("Vote!");
    studentNumButton.addActionListener(new SelectionCounter());

//this code could be added to show a picture of each valedictorian *******EXTRA************
    // John.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    // John.setRolloverIcon(icon);

    //images
    //int NEW_WIDTH = 50;
    //int NEW_HEIGHT = 235;
    //int NEW_WIDTH2 = 290;
    //int NEW_HEIGHT2 = 55;


    ImageIcon header;
    ImageIcon side;
    ImageIcon side2;
    Image image = new ImageIcon("src\\Header_MICHS.jpg").getImage();    
    header = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(290, 55, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    Image image2 = new ImageIcon("src\\lightningbolt2.png").getImage() ;    
    side = new ImageIcon(image2.getScaledInstance(50, 235, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    Image image3 = new ImageIcon("src\\lightningbolt.png").getImage() ;  
    side2 = new ImageIcon(image3.getScaledInstance(50, 235, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    JLabel sideLabel2 = new JLabel(side2);
    JLabel sideLabel = new JLabel(side);
    JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel(header);

    //bottom bar add - the text field and Jbutton
    JPanel studentInfo = new JPanel();
    studentInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    studentInfo.add(studentNumber);
    studentInfo.add(studentNumButton);



    //add the val radio buttons to a panel
    JPanel options1 = new JPanel();
    options1.setLayout(new GridLayout(val2.length,0));
    for(int i=0; i<val2.length;i++){
      options1.add(val2[i]);
    }

    //add the message box to a panel

    options2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
    options2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    options2.add(voteNotification);


    //add the panels to a panel

    options.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    options.add(options1);
    options.add(options2);

    //put the functional things into one panel
    JPanel setup = new JPanel();
    setup.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setup.add(options, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setup.add(studentInfo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //put the pictures around the functional things
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(setup, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    content.add(sideLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    content.add(sideLabel2, BorderLayout.WEST);


    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    window.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.setSize(300,310);
    window.setLocation(550,250);
    window.setVisible(true);  
    window.setResizable(false);
  }
  private static class SelectionCounter implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      voted();
    }
  }//end of SelectionCounter class


  public static class FileHandling{ 
    private Scanner file;
    static DynamicArrayOfString temp;
    String name;

    public void openFile(String name){
      try{
        file = new Scanner(new File(filePath + name)); //gets name=file u want to read
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not find file!");
      }
    }

    public void readFile(){ // retrieves one input from the file for each line
        temp = new DynamicArrayOfString();
      for(int i = 0; file.hasNext(); i++){
        temp.put(i,file.next());
       System.out.printf("%s%n", temp.get(i));
      }
    }

    public int length(){
      return temp.size();
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
      return file.hasNext();
    }

    public String get(int position) {
      if (position >= temp.size())
        return "Nothing";
      else{
        String answer = temp.get(position);
        //System.out.println(temp.get(position));
        return answer;
      }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
      file.close();
    }
  }//end of FileHandling


  private static class CreateFile{
    private static Formatter file2;

    public static void openFile(String name){
      try{
        file2 = new Formatter(filePath + name);
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("you have an error");
      }
    }
    public static void addToFile(String number){
      file2.format("%s%n", number);
    }
    public static void closeFile(){
      file2.close();
    }
  }//end of CreateFile

  static class HintTextField extends JTextField implements FocusListener {

    private final String hint;
    private boolean showingHint;

    public HintTextField(final String hint) {
      super(hint);
      this.hint = hint;
      this.showingHint = true;
      super.addFocusListener(this);
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
      if(this.getText().isEmpty()) {
        super.setText("");
        showingHint = false;
      }
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
      if(this.getText().isEmpty()) {
        super.setText(hint);
        showingHint = true;
      }
    }

    public String getText() {
      return showingHint ? "" : super.getText();
    }
    public void showHint(){
      super.setText(hint);
    this.showingHint=true;
    }
```

Comment: There isn't enough code to understand. If you would post all of your code, that would be much better.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  @tbodt  So you are prepared to look for bugs in 600+ LOC spread across a half-dozen classes?  You'd be in a 'select group'.  Most of us would prefer an SSCCE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If I were to see 1,000 lines of code in a Stack Overflow question, I would faint. I didn't think there would be very much code.

Comment: @tbodt  Of course I am just guessing as to LOC.  It could be 1000 (which SO won't accept) it could be 600 (which can be squeezed in) or it might be 120 (quite doable).  OTOH I am careful to never imply we want to see 'all' the code - just an SSCCE.  :)

Comment: Here is all of the code:

Answer (score 1):

> One of the panels contains my JTextArea. Initially I set is as " ".

What happens if you initially set the text area with some text? Do you see the text?

I'm guessing you don't see the text because of the way you created the textarea:

```
static JTextArea voteNotification = new JTextArea(" ");
```

Maybe try:

```
static JTextArea voteNotification = new JTextArea(2, 30);
```

so the text area has a reasonable preferred size.

Comment: If I put text into the text area at the beginning it does show up. It just doesn't update even when stepping through the code.

Comment: If the text area doesn't update then it means one of two things, either 1) you are blocking the EDT so the GUI can never repaint itself or 2) you don't have a reference to the text area which means you have defined it twice.